# Input feild 1px boarder disappears sometime in top, sometyimes in bottom in android devices

Tags: android, css

I'm using the following code for my input box.

```
.input_box {
    border: 1px solid #002A4A;
    color: #002A4A;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 2px 6px;
}
```

Sometimes the bottom, or some times the top border disappear if I surf the page on android devices.

How can I fix this.?

Comment: Could be to do with the way the page is being zoomed?

Comment: If I zoom a bit then it looks fine..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a margin for your input box, may be the border is overflow by another component

Answer (score 0):

remove padding I think it will work again